# Find function g given by newtons method

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

[image]

### Try:

Well, we know it will succedd as long as $g'(1) < 1$. Notice that

$$ g'(x) = \frac{ (\pi/2) x^3 \cos (\pi x/2) - 3 x^2 \sin (\pi x /2) }{x^6} $$

and $|g'(1)| = 3 $. Thus, the fixed point iteration will fail to spot the root.

To answer b), using Mewton' method $f(x) = x^4 - \sin ( \pi x ) $

and so $g(x_n) = x_n - \frac{ f(x_n ) }{f'(x_n) } $.

is this correct solution?

Comment: Please spell Newton correctly!

Comment: @Neymar, if $|g'(t)| < 1$ the iteration is guaranteed to converge. But is it a true statement that if $|g'(t)| > 1$ the method will not converge?